# Is neo4j CREATE DATABASE transactional?

Tags: database, neo4j, transactions, neo4j-driver

I am using NodeJS and the [neo4j-driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j-driver) package. On server startup I need to ensure that a specific database exists in my neo4j cluster. I therefore implemented this method:

```js
export const ensureAdminDatabaseExists = async () => {
  const session = neo4j
    .driver(
      NEO4J_CONNECTION_URL,
      neo4j.auth.basic(NEO4J_USERNAME, NEO4J_PASSWORD)
    )
    .session();
  await session.writeTransaction((tx) =>
    tx.run('CREATE DATABASE $dbName IF NOT EXISTS', { dbName: 'admin' })
  );
  await session.close();
};
```

If no such database exists in Neo4j and I call this method several times in parallel, then at least one of the transactions will fail with the following error message:

`Neo4jError: Failed to create the specified database 'admin': Database already exists.`

However, if the database exists on startup then no transactions fail. I, therefore, question if the `CREATE DATABASE` query is transactional.

Comment: Should be transactional following to [this](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/4cd5556a5356c8d0d9efe9c8fb6a8b87865c48ed/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/dbms/database/DatabaseManagementServiceImpl.java#L141)